# Remove Column name from array in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am getting format like this in an array
here is my array=

```
  var array= [{"address":"Jaipur"},{"address":"Mumbai"},{"address":"Mumbai"}]
```

I want format like this

```
var array= [

    "Jaipur",
    "Mumbai"
];
```

what things should be done to in JSON so i can get desired array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to get unique values, and [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) it into an array again.

```js
var array= [{"address":"Jaipur"},{"address":"Mumbai"},{"address":"Mumbai"}];

var res = [...new Set(array.map(x => x.address))];

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Amazing.got new knowledge.+1

Comment: please add source of new Set?

Comment: great you just banged the question

Comment: @lalithkumar MDN has all the answers: [Set()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), and your most likely next question will be about the [Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

Answer (score 2):

```js
var array= [{"address":"Jaipur"},{"address":"Mumbai"},{"address":"Mumbai"}];
var address=[];

$.each(array,function(add,val){
address.push(val.address);
});
var address = Array.from(new Set(address));
console.log(address);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `reduce` the array:

```js
var array= [{"address":"Jaipur"},{"address":"Mumbai"},{"address":"Mumbai"}];

var formatedArray = array.reduce((output, item) => {
  if(!output.includes(item.address)) {
    output.push(item.address)
  }
  return output
}, [])

console.log(formatedArray)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 string json = DataTableToJSON(dt_main); 
 jsonnew = @"{""Data"":" + json + "}";



private static string DataTableToJSON(DataTable table)
{

    List<string[]> result = table.Rows
 .Cast<DataRow>()
 .Select(row => row.ItemArray
     .Select(x => x.ToString())
     .ToArray())
 .ToList();

    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    return serializer.Serialize(result);

    //------another method----------------
    //ArrayList arr = new ArrayList(); 
    //List<ArrayList> list = new List<ArrayList>();

    //foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    //{ 
    //    arr = new ArrayList();
    //    foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
    //    { 
    //       arr.Insert(col.Ordinal, row[col]);
    //    }

    //     list.Add(arr); 
    //} 

   // JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
   // return serializer.Serialize(list);

}
```

Comment: Is that really Javascript?  Looks more like Java to me.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
var array= [{"address":"Jaipur"},{"address":"Mumbai"},{"address":"Mumbai"}];
var array_new=[];
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    array_new.push(array[i].address);
}
```

Comment: Yes, if repetition is not an issue then this will work

Comment: Well, i guess you didn't read the question because if you look at the example, the op want's to remove duplications.