# Remove Column name from JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, object

I am new to Javascript and am trying to get the below output from my_result object. I tried using map function but am unable to get the desired output.

```
const my_result = '[{"result":true, "count":42}, {"result":false, "count":30}]'; 
//Output
[ [ true, 42 ], [false, 30] ]
```

I found similar example here here but I am not able to figure out how I can perform similar operation for multiple row count. ([Remove Column name from array in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44110484/remove-column-name-from-array-in-json))

my_result can have variable row count based on the table I am pulling the data from.

Comment: You want it as an array of objects, (`[ { 'true': 42 }, { 'false': 30 } ]`) an array of arrays (`[ [ true, 42 ], [false, 30] ]`)or as a single object (`{ 'true': 42, 'false': 30 }`). Right now your output is not valid JavaScript.

Comment: sorry edited the post now, I want it as an array of arrays. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const my_result = '[{"result":true, "count":42}, {"result":false, "count":30}]'; 

const res = JSON.parse(my_result).map(Object.values)

console.log(res)
```

Comment: If you wanted a subset of the fields or just to be more explicit, you could use `.map(e => [e.result, e.count])` instead.

Answer (score -1):

Map works great.

```js
const my_result = '[{"result":true, "count":42}, {"result":false, "count":30}]';

const formatted = JSON.parse(my_result).map(o => ({
  [o.result]: o.count
}));

console.log(formatted);
```